# IntelliJ Won't open (even after re-install)

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I recently wanted to try to again update my IntelliJ IDEA because I had problems before (I still have problems hence this post). I've tried re-installing, fiddling with VM options, all what the internet says, but nothing provides any answers.

It starts when I click the .exe file of IntelliJ. It will briefly pop up in the task manager, use about 20% CPU for about 8 seconds and then disappear. It doesn't open later also. I've also tried to start it from the CLI, but that gives me this:

[cli-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdQ9l.png)

I currently have IntelliJ 2019 since it's the only version that works, all the other versions I tried have the same problem. Does anyone know how I can resolve this (I'm running on Windows 10)?

Comment: Have you tried all steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my windows 10. To fix it go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\` folder and try to remove `idea64.exe.jdk` file, then run IntelliJ again.

P.s. I'm using JetBrains Toolbox, so all files that need to run IntelliJ will be placed into `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains` automatically after installation.